# libPoads.a file is missing in CocoaLumberjack pod install

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, cocoalumberjack

I am trying to install `CocoaLumberjack` using `pod install`. Installation successfully completed but `libPods.a` file is missing in my project. Without this lib file I am getting this following error,

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-CocoaLumberjack
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am not sure why this file is missing I couldn't find any solution for this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks is advance.

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you open the xworkspace that Cocoapods created, instead of xcodeproj?

Or check if you install pod in the right directory. I mean in the directory of your Project:

```
cd myProject
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check the Configurations in the Info of your Project if the pod is chosen in the Configuration Set.